# Does $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ ever admit a difference set when $n$ is odd?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

A [difference set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set) of a group $G$ is a subset $D\subseteq G$ with the property that there exists an integer $\lambda>0$ such that for every non-identity member $g$ of $G$, there exist exactly $\lambda$ ordered pairs $(a,b)\in D\times D$ such that $g=ab^{-1}$. Note that $D=G$ is a difference set with $\lambda=|G|$, and so we typically only consider nontrival difference sets.

[Davis](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16666554031641448939) showed that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ admits a nontrivial difference set when $n$ is a power of $2$. Are there any known difference sets when $n$ is odd? Perhaps cyclotomic difference sets?

As far as I know, the [Paley-type construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set#Known_difference_sets) Douglas Zare suggests in the comments (letting $D$ be the set of nonzero perfect squares in $\mathrm{GF}(n^2)$ when $n$ is prime) is only guaranteed to work when $n^2$ is $3\bmod 4$ (which never happens). However, there are hopefully weaker sufficient conditions for $n$ to satisfy, and I think the literature discusses this in the context of "cyclotomic difference sets," but I am not familiar with these results.

Comment: What is a difference set?

Comment: A reference to Davis's paper, and a clarification as to what ${\mathbb Z}_n$ is (cyclic group, cyclotomic integers, or p-adics?) would also help.

Comment: @WillSawin a difference set in an abelian group $G$ is any subset $D \subset G$ so that each non-identity $g \in G$ is expressible as a difference $d-d'$ of elements in $D$. One typically extends this by requiring that each $g$ be so expressible in $k \geq 1$ different ways.

Comment: @TerryTao see Davis, Difference sets in abelian 2-groups, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A Volume 57, Issue 2, July 1991, Pages 262–286. Elsevier paywall here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659190050Q

Comment: Are you restricting to having one repetition of each possible difference? If not, then you can do things like look at the squares in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, a classic construction.

Comment: @Douglas Zare, Doesn't that construction require $p^2$ to be $3 \bmod 4$?

Comment: FYI - I significantly edited the question to account for the comments made by Will Sawin, Terry Tao and Douglas Zare.

Comment: Oh, right, I had overlooked that the restriction to $p^k \equiv 3 \mod 4$ would eliminate $p^2$.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't want to allow $D=G$.

Comment: @David Speyer - Agreed, I only want nontrivial difference sets.

Comment: Being on the wrong side of the paywall, and conflating the set D with its cardinality, I don't know if Davis looks at the associated equation $D^2 - D = \lambda(n^2 - 1)$ in the cited paper.  Does he?  Does anyone else in the combinatorial design literature talk about allowed values for $\lambda$?

Comment: There may be something in Kopilovich, L. E., Difference sets in noncyclic abelian groups (Russian. English summary),  Kibernetika (Kiev) 1989, no. 2, 20-23, 133; translation in 
Cybernetics 25 (1989), no. 2, 153–157, MR1009696 (90g:05047). The author looks for difference sets of at most 100 elements in noncyclic abelian groups. The work is continued by Lopez and Garcia Sanchez, On the existence of abelian difference sets with $100\lt k\le150$, J. Combin. Math. Combin. Comput. 23 (1997) 97–112, MR1432750 (98a:05029).

Comment: Arasu, K. T., Burkett, Grady, and Linger, Michael, 
Existence status of some previously open abelian difference sets,  Discrete Math. 306 (2006), no. 14, 1467–1473, MR2245181 (2007j:05025) shows there is no $(841,120,17)$ difference set in $({\bf Z}/29{\bf Z})^2$.

Comment: Here's an online database of difference sets including non-cyclic, abelian cases: http://www.ccrwest.org/diffsets.html I checked the case $\vert D \vert < 150$, only to find one (possible) example over (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2. It says $PG(4,3)$ gives a $(121,40,13)$ difference set over (\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})^2, but I thought it should be a "cyclic" one (i.e., over the cyclic group of order $121$). So, unless I'm missing something, it's an error, and if that's the case, there seems to be no known small example. In any case, such difference sets seem to be very rare if there's one at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such difference sets exist. There exist (nontrivial) difference sets with

$|G|  =  q^{d+1}[1+(q^{d+1}-1)/(q-1)]$,

$|D|   =  q^d(q^{d+1}-1)/(q-1)$,

$\lambda  =  q^d(q^d-1)/(q-1)$,

whenever $q$ is a prime power (R. L. McFarland, A family of difference sets in non-cyclic groups, JCT A, 15 (1973), pp. 1-10). More precisely, such difference sets exist in any abelian group of order $v$ which contains an elementary abelian subgroup of order $q^{d+1}$.

Take $q=7$ and $d=1$, for instance. This shows that a nontrivial difference set in $(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^2$ exists.